# Can JavaScript perform nth+1 line of code without waiting nth line if there no async operations in some cases?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, pug

### How I doubted in it after 5 year of JavaScript experience

Too rare case: I need to build some JavaScript by Webpack (source: TypeScript) for ... PUG preprocessor! My library (`MixinArgumentValidator`) is too complicated to write it in JavaScript, and also uses some libraries. In below project structure, `OutputFileGenerator.ts` generates the `MixinArgumentsValidator.pug`.

[image]

`MixinArgumentsValidator.pug` contains just `-` symbol (in Pug, it means raw JavaScript which must be executed during preprocessing) and minified JavaScript code from `MixinArgumentsValidator.js`:

[image]

In the point view of theory, if to include `MixinArgumentsValidator.pug` in other pug file, the global variable `MixinArgumentsValidator` must be available. It so but... from the second pug compilation.

**Experiment**

I left exactly 2 pug files (entry points) in my project. Also, I added below console logs to `MixinArgumentsValidator.pug`:

[image]

In first pass, `MixinArgumentsValidator` is undefined, but in second pass, it is available:

[image]

I did not find any Timeouts, Intervals or Promises in compiled code. The `MixinArgumentsValidator` execution is completely synchronous:

[image]

If you want to check the Webpack's code for async element, I added link to [beautified version](https://pastebin.com/Aead7weW) of `MixinArgumentsValidator.js`.

**Webpack settings**

In above experiment, webpack's `output` settings are:

```js
output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: "[name].js",
  libraryTarget: "umd"
}
```

I also tried:

```
output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: "[name].js",
  libraryTarget: "umd",
  library: "MixinArgumentsValidator"
}
```

For this settings, `MixinArgumentsValidator` is object, not function, but it also visible from the second pass.

[image]

Thanks for reading this questions.

**Pug's top level `this`**

My library exists in the pug's top-level context from the first pass, and top-level context almost does not change from the second pass (just `input_char: '>'` has been added from the second pass).

```
Object [global] {
  global: [Circular],
  clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
  clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
  setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] { [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function] },
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function]
  },
  '__core-js_shared__': {
    versions: [ [Object] ],
    wks: {
      toStringTag: Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag),
      _hidden: Symbol(Symbol._hidden),
      toPrimitive: Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive),
      hasInstance: Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance),
      isConcatSpreadable: Symbol(Symbol.isConcatSpreadable),
      iterator: Symbol(Symbol.iterator),
      match: Symbol(Symbol.match),
      replace: Symbol(Symbol.replace),
      search: Symbol(Symbol.search),
      species: Symbol(Symbol.species),
      split: Symbol(Symbol.split),
      unscopables: Symbol(Symbol.unscopables),
      asyncIterator: Symbol(Symbol.asyncIterator),
      observable: Symbol(Symbol.observable)
    },
    keys: { IE_PROTO: 'Symbol(IE_PROTO)_2.wy4w0dx9di' },
    'symbol-registry': {},
    symbols: {},
    'op-symbols': {}
  },
  indent_handlebars: false,
  MixinArgumentsValidator: Object [Module] {
    MixinArgumentsValidator: [Getter],
    ObjectDataValidatorTypes: [Getter]
  },
  input_char: '>'
}
```

Comment: can't see the full `!function(e, t)` statement so no idea what is happening there, is the `MixinArgumentsValidator` set in this statement? Or probably it is set in some statement after the log?
Also it might be helpful to copy out the related statements to a .js file and execute it directly to see if it works fine.

Comment: It's hard to understand your questions and most of you statements. Could you re-write it with better grammar and wording? I think your primary question is can synchronous code run asynchronously?

Comment: @Surely, Thank you for the reading of my question. I published the [beautified version](https://pastebin.com/Aead7weW) of `!function ...`.

Comment: @SILENT, Thank you for the reading of my question. I am sorry for my bad English. Please understand that I wrote so because of poor English, not because of laziness. So I can to try to rewrite only if I will be notified, which expressions I need to re-write.

Comment: works fine if I run the script you pasted in browser (with changing the `global` to `window`). In your code, can you change the `console.log(MixinArgumentsValidator);` to `console.log(global.MixinArgumentsValidator);` and see if it works?

Comment: @Surely, It works! It looks like in below my solution `global` and `this` are same. But the riddle is still left... Why we can not call it just `MixinArgumentsValidator` in first compilation of incremental building?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu based on those facts, I think it is because at the time of logging, the global object has not yet assigned to the `this` scope, i.e. if it is run in browser, i assume at some stage the items in the global object will be copied into `window` object, but at the time of the log this has not yet happened so it is undefined. In second pass, the value that been logged is actually the value created in first pass.

Comment: @Surely, Thank you for the assumption! I'll remember it as hypothesis.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, `MixinArgumentsValidator` is a free variable. So in your example, it doesn't mean that this is a global variable. If you want to access variables assigned to the global context you should get a reference on a global object. For nodejs this is a `global` variable for browser this is a `window` you can also use code like this `(function() {return this || eval.call(null, 'this');}())`. So maybe in your case when you run code first time you already have a declared variable with the name `MixinArgumentsValidator` in a scope above. And you just experience "variable shadowing" effect.

Comment: @maksimr, you answered the question! Very sorry that bounty has has ended ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know the cause, but the safest way to receive the desired effect is:

1. Encapsulate the imports to reduce the global space pollution:

```
output: {
 path: __dirname,
 filename: "[name].js",
 libraryTarget: "umd",
 library: "MixinArgumentsValidatorExports"
}
```

2. Because exports are exists in global space from the first pass, it's possible to extract them:

```
include HikariPug-Kernel/MixinArgumentsValidator/MixinArgumentsValidator

-
  const MixinArgumentsValidator = this.MixinArgumentsValidatorExports.MixinArgumentsValidator;
  const ObjectDataValidatorTypes = this.MixinArgumentsValidatorExports.ObjectDataValidatorTypes;
```

Or shorter:

```js
  const { MixinArgumentsValidator, ObjectDataValidatorTypes } = this.MixinArgumentsValidatorExports;
```

### What if to compile without `library: "MixinArgumentsValidatorExports"`?

The usage becomes easier, but global space pollution will increase.

```js
const { MixinArgumentsValidator, ObjectDataValidatorTypes } = this;
```